# How to set variable for kettle MongoDB Input step from Java?

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle

In my KTR, I have a MongoDBInput. I need to invoke it through Java class.. 
I need to set the value of Query Expression variable through java. 
I am not able to find MongoDBInput Step in org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.* . 
Can anyone guide me how to set the value of Query Expression variable from java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Job job = new Job(null, jobMeta);       
job.shareVariablesWith(jobMeta);
jobMeta.setParameterValue("nameVar", "toset");
```